# Command "ls" can't find existing file

Tags: macos, terminal, printf, ls

I am attempting to sanitize my filenames without actually renaming them in preparation for "ls -l" in Mac OS terminal.

I am using printf %q like this:

ls -l $(printf %q "filenamewithspaceinit")

However, if a space is present in the file name (which normally elicits an error that I was trying to correct with this code), ls has the gall to repeat the exact file name with backslash and space that it would recognize if I simply autocompleted the file name with tab in shell and claim that there is "No such file or directory."

I am very exasperated with the command right now.  I thought that printf was supposed to produce navigable and proper file names.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant to say that ls -l "$(printf %q "filenamewithspaceinit")" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave out the `%q` so you don't quote it twice?

```
15:23:54-qsario@MacBook-Air:~/test$ ls
foo bar

15:24:01-qsario@MacBook-Air:~/test$ ls -l "$(printf %q 'foo bar')"
ls: foo\ bar: No such file or directory

15:24:04-qsario@MacBook-Air:~/test$ ls -l "$(printf 'foo bar')"
-rw-r--r--  1 qsario  staff  0 Aug  5 15:19 foo bar
```